# PHP wordpress using checkbox post meta

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This is probably a bit of a basic question, but I am a bit lost.
Basically, I am trying to create a checkbox meta state within a custom post type. I then want to check if that checkbox has been selected to alter what is displayed in my theme.

So here is what I have:

my custom-post-class:

```
function slide_box() {

    $slide_stored_meta = get_post_meta((int)$_REQUEST['post'] );

?>

<div>
<label for="slide-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="slide-checkbox" id="slide-checkbox" value="yes" <?php if ( isset ( $slide_stored_meta['slide-checkbox'] ) ) checked( $slide_stored_meta['slide-checkbox'][0], 'yes' ); ?> />
<?php _e( 'Display Title and Excerpt?', 'prfx-textdomain' )?>
</label>
</div>

<?php
}

add_action('save_post','slide_save_meta');
function slide_save_meta($postID) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {

    // Checks for input and saves
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'slide-checkbox' ] ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $postID, 'slide-checkbox', 'yes' );
    } else {
            update_post_meta( $postID, 'slide-checkbox', 'no' );
    }

    }
}
?>
```

It seems to save it ok, as when I update the post it stays checked on unchecked correctly.

Next my theme template file:

```
<?php $slider = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'slide', 'posts_per_page'=>20, 'suppress_filters'=>0 )); ?>

            <?php if ($slider->have_posts()) : while($slider->have_posts()) : $slider->the_post(); ?>    

            **<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID), 'slide-checkbox', true) { ?>**
```

Answer (score 0):

Why did you use zero index?
Try direct variable:

```
checked( $slide_stored_meta['slide-checkbox'], "yes")
```